# Subversion :Update to head

Tags: svn

Does Subversion "Update to head" merge newer Head files with those which I have changed locally? Or does it only updated files which I have not changed locally, waiting to merge when I commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an `svn update` it will merge HEAD into your local changes - automatically, if Subversion is able to resolve the differences cleanly. Otherwise the file will be marked as conflicted, and you'll have to resolve the merge manually.

You can get an overview of the incoming changes by running:

```
svn status -u -v
```

This might output (example is from the [Subversion documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.status)):

```
$ svn status -u -v
M      *        44        23    sally     README
M               44        20    harry     bar.c
       *        44        35    harry     stuff/trout.c
D               44        19    ira       stuff/fish.c
A                0         ?     ?        stuff/things/bloo.h
Status against revision:   46
```

You can see that `README` was changed both locally (the letter `M`) and in the repository (the asterisk `*`), so running `svn update` here will result in a merge for this file.